# Check box validation issue?

Tags: javascript

I have the following code to validate if any of three checkboxes are not checked:

```
    function checkBoxes(form) {
       if (
    form.checkbox1.checked == false ||
    form.checkbox2.checked == false ||
    form.checkbox3.checked == false) 
    {
        alert ('must fill in the last 3 checkboxes');
        return false;
    } else {    
        return true;
    }
}
```

And called once submitted via a submit button:

```
<form method="post" onsubmit="return checkBoxes(this);">`
```

It doesn't work, why exactly?

Comment: It is only supposed to validate if all three checkboxes are checked.

Comment: Use `&&` instead of `||`

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function checkBoxes(form) {
     if (
        form.checkbox1.checked == null ||
        form.checkbox2.checked == null ||
        form.checkbox3.checked == null) 
        {
            alert ('checkbox is null');
            return false;
        } 
    else  if (
    form.checkbox1.checked == false ||
    form.checkbox2.checked == false ||
    form.checkbox3.checked == false) 
    {
        alert ('must fill in the last 3 checkboxes');
        return false;
    } else {

        return true;
    }
}
</script>
```

Add that to know if a checkbox is null